# How precisely can change in temperatute be modeled without a thermometer?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, error-analysis, models

This is mainly a gastronomical question, however, it is not exactly trivial. I'll present the setting in the form of a problem:

In order to make a dessert, the recipe states that we have to "carefully raise the syrup's temperature to $110^\circ [\mathrm{C}]$".
If the syrup's solution is comprised of $m_w$ grams of water, $m_s$ grams of sugar, and the heat capacity of the water and sugar is $c_w$ and $c_s$ respectively, how much time will the syrup take to get to the desired temperature if the heat entry is $E$?

---

The solution for this is problem is basically just solving for a function $f:\mathbb{R}_t\rightarrow T$ from the time value $\mathbb{R}_t$ to the temperature (of the syrup) $T$. I have two questions:

1. What is the function $f$?
2. Is there some missing data in the formulation of the problem (like the geometric properties of the pan in which the syrup is heated, or the ambient temperature and pressure?)

Comment: There is a very reliable measure of temperature with no thermometer for the very narrow domain of syrups in warm terrestrial kitchens: the consistency of syrup which is reached when your thermometer reads 110 degrees is the consistency of syrup which forms threads of about 5 centimeters when dribbled from the spoon. I am lost in reverie, imagining all the delicious data tables we could add to the CRC handbook...

Comment: Haha, this is great info, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The inputs are not sufficient to determine the output.

To see this, consider that you could put the syrup in a big flat thin bowl made by lining a baking sheet with aluminum foil to get the right shape, then carefully removing the sheet leaving just the foil. The syrup would then make a very thin layer in close contact with the foil.bIf you put it into a bonfire, pull it out at “just the right time”, you’d have the appropriate temperature in a few seconds to a minute. Or we could put it in a double walled insulating container inside a sous-vide bath, and it might take a few days to come up to temperature.

So: just knowing the heat input does not tell me the time that it takes.

Now, this is the subject of a few relatively universal properties that we collectively call “physical transport phenomena”. In particular, when you put this into a pot and put it on top of a heat source, the heat flow into the pot is going to happen at a rate that depends on the temperature difference between the hotter heat source and the cooler pot. And if you are far away from phase changes, then the temperature of the stuff in the pot will increase as heat is added. These are two very common near-universal properties, “as the pot heats up, its higher temperature means that heat flows slower and slower into it.” So there is a pretty universal function for this combination and it is an exponential decay from the initial temperature $T_0$ to the equilibrium temperature $T_\text{eq}$:
$$T(t)=T_0 +(T_\text{eq}-T_0)e^{-t/s}.$$
Here it is tempting to think that $T_\text{eq}$ is the temperature of the burner, but it is not, because there is also a heat loss to the external world which is also at a relatively consistent temperature. It is also tempting to think that $T_\text{eq}$ is the target temperature, but if you do that then it takes infinite time to get there, so in practice you want to heat it so that the burner is hotter than your target temperature, but the hotter you go the shorter the time is that you can pull the syrup out at the right temperature.

The real message is not, however, $T_\text{eq},$ it is this characteristic time $s$. What happened when I put the syrup into a thin layer in a thin aluminum bowl was, the high surface area and thinness of the bowl creates a very low characteristic time  $s$, and this combines with the bonfire, which is the large $T_\text{eq},$ to make the heat transfer so fast. Conversely, the double-walled thermos has a very low $s$ and combined with $T_\text{eq}\approx T_\text{target},$ of course this will take a very long time.

The $s$ contains the parameters that you are missing to physically model your problem, it contains the “mass” of the liquid that you are turning to syrup compared against the heat rate of the burner-to-pot connection and a bunch of other little things besides.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use your heat transfer function, and will numerically approximate the value of $s$ with more data and equipment.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the function you posted. Assuming a nonzero value for $s$, at times $t_0=0$ and $t_\infty=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}t$, we should get: $T(t_0)=T_{\mathrm{eq}}$ and $T(t_\infty)=T_0$. I trust this should be all the way around? Maybe its fixable by interchanging $T_0$ and $T_{\mathrm{eq}}$

Comment: So when I say equilibrium temperature, I mean the temperature at which the pot is going to be at equilibrium if you let it sit on the heat forever, I don't mean the environment temperature around the pot. When I say $T_0$ I mean the temperature that it starts at. Obviously if you mean the opposite things by those then yes you need to interchange them